# Setup RDP in Widows 10 Hyper-V

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to this whole RDP and Hyper-V thing. I have read in many places about connecting to a hyper-v VM using RDP? What is this and how do I do this? I am trying to set this up for a VM running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS...

Comment: You need to add xRDP, if you did a quick create of Ubuntu, it should be pre-configured.  You can set up manually per: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12429

Comment: @essjae That link doesn't work for 20.04. Substituting `20.04` instead of `18.04` doesn't work. It gives a `404` error

Comment: The process should be similar, if you're having trouble, I'd suggest using the quick create option then, as that should configure it for you.  There are several guides for 20.04, try: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-remote-desktop-access-from-windows-10